# Rails: filling in model attributes during creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have a **many-to-many** relationship between User and Task model.

A task can have many users, but it should keep track of its original creator (if a user creates one by `@user.tasks.create`). I was wondering how could I do this.

I would have to create a new column field called "creator" in the tasks table. I could then initalise a task in the following way:

```
@user.tasks.create(:creator=>@user)
```

Is there a way of not having to add the arguments since the creator will always be the user that instantiated the task.

Thanks!

EDIT

My User model has:

```
 has_many :taskization
 has_many :tasks, :through => :taskization
```

My Tasks model has:

```
  has_many :taskization
  has_many :users, :through => :taskization
```

Comment: Can you share your models code?

Comment: My models basically only have the many-to-many relation ... I have updated the question to show this. However, this is more of a general question since I have been wondering how to do this for a while - not directly application specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you're indicating that the 'original_creator' is an attribute of the Task. For each Task record, you want to keep track of which User originally created it.

So, modeling that seems like you would require both:

```
# return the User object of the original task creator
@original_creator_user = @task.original_creator
```

as well as

```
# get all users of this task
@users = @task.users
```

to work.

This requires two different relationships between `Task` objects and `User` objects.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # tasks for this user
  has_many :taskization
  has_many :tasks, :through => :taskization

  # tasks this user was the original creator of
  has_many :created_tasks, :class_name => "Task" 

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  # users of this task
  has_many :taskization
  has_many :users, :through => :taskization

  # user who originally created this class
  belongs_to :original_creator, :class_name => "User"

end
```

Notice that the 'creator' relationship is not a `:through` task, it's a relationship directly between the two objects.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your answer. Quick question, is Steve's answer also applicable?

Comment: There are different ways to approach this, but I think if you add the associations above that should be enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin - no question the associations are necessary to access the creator attribute, but absent a callback, how is the value of that attribute set in the first place without calling something like `@user.tasks.create(:creator=>@user)` when the task is created? That part isn't clear to me.

Comment: @SteveRowley There are a couple ways to do it. I'd probably do a call back on create that would set the value to the user that created the record.

Comment: Hi @KevinBedell, I just implemented the code above (a bit late really!). I realised that user.tasks.create doesnt set the tasks original_creator.

Comment: I have the same doubt as @SteveRowley. Could you update your answer to show how this call back on create could be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to put the creator attribute in the join model (Taskization). If you do that (say, with this migration),

```
class AddCreatorIdToTaskizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :taskizations, :creator_id, :integer
  end
end
```

you can then add a callback to taskization.rb

```
before_create do |taskization|
  taskization.creator_id  = taskization.user_id
end
```

that gets you where you want. It's possible that you could do a similar callback in the Task model if you decide that's where the creator attribute belongs, but I haven't thought that through fully.

Comment: Note that Kevin's answer is spot on regarding the need to create a new association as well. Having read that, based on what you're asking I think it makes sense to put that attribute in Task model after all. To do that you'd just add the creator_id column to Tasks and set up the callback in the Task object (and set up the relationships along the lines of Kevin's answer).

The only possible advantage of setting it up in the join model would be if you wanted to get all the users working on tasks created by so-and-so. You'd have to set up yet another association to enable that.

Comment: brilliant - thanks for your answer. I think Kevin's answer is directly related to my question (correct me if I am wrong) - but from your answer I learn that the join table can keep information of each relation between Task and User - which I think I might need in the near future. Thanks a bunch!